# What inspired the creation of Cyrus Smith?

Tags: history-of, inspiration, jules-verne, the-mysterious-island

What inspired the character of Cyrus Smith in the novel *The Mysterious Island* by Jules Verne? Did Verne ever explain the concept behind the character?

Answer (score 2):

Jules Verne's novels typically feature a scientist character, who usually finds solutions to problems, and explains what is happening to the other characters, and by extension to the reader.

Examples are Jacques Paganel in In Search of the Castaways, Professor Pierre Aronnax in 20000 Leagues under the Sea, Professor Otto Lidenbrock in Journey to the Center of the Earth, etc.

So, the caracter of Cyrus Smith clearly fits this trope.